# image width 100 % when the height larger than the width with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make a wordpress theme ,so my code is :

```
<div class="post-thumb">
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
</div>
```

i would when the height is bigger than the width , the width=100% , height=auto;
and when the width is bigger than the height , the height:100% , width=auto;

i have tried to do that with javascript , but it didn't work !

```
var landscape = $(".post-thumb img ").css('width');
var portrait = $(".post-thumb img ").css('height');

if (landscape > portrait){
$(".post-thumb img").height('100%') .width('auto');}
else {
$(".post-thumb img").width('100%') .height('auto');}
);
},
});
```

any solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the image as a background image and use background-cover

```
.post-thumb{
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use jQuery when you can use CSS?

```
.post-thumb-img {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

The inclusion of the `auto` pieces are because older versions of Firefox don't look at `min-` declarations unless the regular declarations are explicit.

Comment: when i do that , the width image or height image will be too big , 
.post-thumb {
overflow:hidden;
} so a big part of image will not be showing

Comment: oh you are not looking for full coverage, you are looking for a contain kind of setup? then switch `min` to `max`! i'll mod my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var landscape = $(".post-thumb img ").width();
var portrait = $(".post-thumb img").height();
if (landscape > portrait)
{
   $(".post-thumb img").height('100%') .width('auto');
}
else 
{
   $(".post-thumb img").width('100%') .height('auto');
}
```